# How do we make swap the demo page to main landing page?

Tags: cpanel

Hi I currently have a demo page on my cpanel and I would like to make it the main landing page.  How do I proceed; for instance to change it from website.com/demo -> website.com
[image: pa]

Comment: Do you need to preserve your current home page?

Comment: no I essentially, want the demo6 as my new home page

Answer (score 2):

Simply copy (don't `move` ) all the files in your demo directory up one level to the `public_html` directory.

You can do that in cpanel file manager.

To double check that you have done it properly change the name of the demo directory and make sure your site still works.

Once you have done that you can then safely delete the demo directory

**[UPDATE]** Also, don't forget you need to be certain your demo page is index.html or whatever the index page is named.  This should replace your current home page.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @JérémiePerrault if it answered your question, be sure to accept the answer so others know there is one.